# In trello, ive unarchived my list but check list no longer displays

Tags: trello

I unarchived my list but check list no longer displays - despite on list view it indicates checklist with 0/4 being displayed

Answer (score 1):

This is not normal as restoring an archived item should restore all of its content, including checklists with 0/x elements checked.

I noticed that, sometimes, after restoring an item and opening it, the content takes some time to load (comments, checklist, attached files,...) so you could wait a bit or reload the page.

Maybe this is a display problem, you could try with a different browser or device, but that would be weird.

If it's still not working you should contact the [Trello Support](https://trello.com/contact) from the contact page (not the Trello Community), they are in the best position to help in that case. Even if you start inspecting the code and see a problem in the console for instance, you'll probably need to contact them.